# symfony2 gmail mail not been sent from new server

Tags: symfony, gmail, swiftmailer

I have a server on which my swiftmailer configuration works fine and mails are sent ok, but I'm deploying on a new server and mails aren't sent from it.

I already received a mail from Google saying it blocked an email for security and said it was me who sent the email, but still no emails from the new server are being sent and I'm not receiving any more alerts from Google.

Any ideas of what might be going wrong.? Like I said, it is working fine from the old server so I don't think it has anything to do with the Symfony configuration because it is the same.

Comment: check if the port (depending on your conf) is open

Comment: It should be open, because the first time I sent an email google alerted me on the sender account, so it means the mail got to google. Any ways, do you know wich port gmail uses?

Comment: If you got a security alert, I think you need to talk to them, looks like they blocked something for you

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to solve it, hope it helps someone in the future.
Reading in google's help center found this out:

> Still having trouble signing in?
>   If you still can’t sign in to your account on the app, try the following:
>   On your device’s browser, go to https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
>   Enter your username and password, then enter the letters on the screen.
>   Go back to the app and try signing in again.

I had the browser in my laptop openned with that account, clicked the link and after that agreed to unlocking the device, tried to send an email again and it worked :D